# When using numericupdown to expand/collapse treeView nodes. Why the collapse part is not working?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, treeview

I have a treeView in my form1 designer.
The treeView variable name is: treeViewMS1

When i'm running my program the treeView is automatic expanded to level 1:

[image: Expanded level 1]

Now if i click on the numericUpDown and change the value to 2 then:

[image: Expanded level 2]

So the expanded part is working fine when i change of the numericUpDown by one up the expanded is working fine.

Now when it's on level 2 and i change the numericUpDown back to value 1 that's level 1 instead get back to my first screenshot Expanded level 1 it's getting back to the root level 0.

and i want that the collapse part will move only one level back but it dosen't matter if i'm on expanded level 2 or 3 or 5 it will allways jump to 0 to the root.

This is the numericUpDown value changed event:

```
decimal oldValue;
        private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (numericUpDown1.Value > oldValue)
            {
                ExpandToLevel(treeViewMS1.Nodes, (int)numericUpDown1.Value);
            }
            else
            {               
                CollapseToLevel(treeViewMS1.Nodes, (int)numericUpDown1.Value);
            }
            oldValue = numericUpDown1.Value;          
        }
```

And this is the ExpandToLevel method:

```
void ExpandToLevel(TreeNodeCollection nodes, int level)
        {
            if (level > 0)
            {
                foreach (TreeNode node in nodes)
                {
                    node.Expand();
                    ExpandToLevel(node.Nodes, level -1);
                }
            }
        }
```

And the CollapseToLevel method:

```
void CollapseToLevel(TreeNodeCollection nodes, int level)
        {
            if (level > 0)
            {
                foreach (TreeNode node in nodes)
                {
                    node.Collapse();
                    CollapseToLevel(node.Nodes, level - 1);
                }
            }
        }
```

If i was on expanded level 2 and moved the numericUpDown value only by one instead collapse only by one level it's jumping and collapsing it to the root:

[image: Collapsed]

You can see the numericUpdown is on value 1 i moved it back from 2.
But the treeView is on the root node and not the level 1.

I tried to use a regular button click event added a button and called the CollapseToLevel inside but same result. I thought maybe there is a problem with the numericUpDown but the expand is working fine it's only the collapse that is not working.

Answer (score 1):

The TreeView.Nodes collection is every node in the TreeView.  In your CollapseToLevel() code you are collapsing every node without checking for some indicator of depth or path to the current node.  So, when you are done you will have all nodes collapsed, which is exactly what your image portrays.  You need to add code here to evaluate the depth of the node before collapsing it.

Comment: cdkMoose could you please show me an example on how to do it ?

Comment: Each node has a level property which tells you how deep in the tree it lives.  You should compare against that value for both collapsing and expanding to see if this node should be changed.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this:
In the Form1_Load event i did:

```
SetToLevel(treeViewMS1.Nodes, 1);
```

In my case i wanted it to begin by default in level 1.

Then in the numericupdown1 changed value event:

```
private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SetToLevel(treeViewMS1.Nodes, (int)numericUpDown1.Value);
        }
```

Then the method SetToLevel:

```
void SetToLevel(TreeNodeCollection nodes, int level)
        {
            foreach (TreeNode node in nodes)
            {
                node.Collapse(false);
            }            
            ExpandToLevel(nodes, level);
        }
```

And last the method EXpandToLevel:

```
void ExpandToLevel(TreeNodeCollection nodes, int level)
        {
            if (level > 0)
            {
                foreach (TreeNode node in nodes)
                {
                    node.Expand();
                    ExpandToLevel(node.Nodes, level -1);
                }
            }
        }
```

And now it's working perfect like i wanted it to work.
When changing the numericupdown value it's changing the node tree expand/collapse levels.